# if rss feed has only one item how to go straight to its detail view without using a table

Tags: iphone, rss

I have an rss feed with only one item in it.I am trying to go straight to showing its details without having to go through a table view to do it.

I have a different rss feed working in my app that has multiple items. I have this working with a table view.I was looking online and all I could find was how to display a feed through a table view.

Does anyone know how to display the singular item from the feed in an app?
or of any online tutorials?

Any and all help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse the feed and insted of showing in tableview ,show it in a label or textview .

Comment: The way i have it set up with the feed that has a table view is that it passes the chosen item to the detail view.How do i just pass the item without choosing it?I don't know how.

Comment: now looking at your feed , which has only one item , so you can display the feed by drawing your view without tableview.Instead of tableview use some labels to display title and description.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what u trying to ask through your question. It sounds simple but can you elaborate or give url of Rss feed links for understaning ur  query...

Comment: ok the feed is:     //www.clontarfrugby.com/youth-mini-rugby/code-of-ethics/feed/rss/     It shows whats on the web page in an rss feed as one item. I'm trying to display this item in an iphone app without having to choose the item in a table view beforehand.Just display it straight off the bat.

Comment: you just want to display a particular element in the detail view right.

Answer (score 0):

If you've parsed your data already, you have it stored in a set of variables, right?

So now you just want a particular data to display in detail view for this if you use (UIWebView for DetailView) used this or a particular you wish to publish in the details view:-

```
– loadHTMLString:baseURL:
```

Sets the main page content and base URL.

`- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL`

Parameters

string

The content for the main page.

baseURL

The base URL for the content.

k...